# SOAP client produces memory error by large response

Tags: php, web-services, soap, out-of-memory

I'm stuck with a strange issue. Below my code:

```
$response = $client->__soapCall('ProcessXmlString', [['xmlRequest' => $xml]]);
```

XML is something like this:

```
<columns code="..">
    <column id="..">
        <field>...</field>
        <label>test</label>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <ask>false</ask>
        <operator>none</operator>
        <from></from>
        <to></to>
        <finderparam>...</finderparam>
    </column>
</columns>
```

When I run this code I get a memory error:

*Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65183479 bytes) ...*

As you can see the response is just about 60MB's. I thought SoapClient just handle things in chunks? (request with less data works perfectly)

I don't want to set my memory limit higher but want to handle response part by part.

I don't really get it why this error occurred. Does anybody has a idea / solution?

I'm using php version 5.6 and SOAP version 1.2

Thanks in advance,

Niels

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use XMLREADER for large (anything above 10mb) XML files.

XML Reader is a so called pull parser. Advantage of that is that you can start parsing without loading the entire fill into the memory (like SimpleXML or DOMDocument does).

Once you get to the level/node that you need, pass that part of the xml to simpleXML.

An example:

```
<?php
$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open('example.xml');


$searchfor='Customer'; //nodename you're intending to find


while ($xml->read()){
    $nodename=$xml->localName;
    if ($nodename==$searchfor &&  $xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT){ // does nodename match what we're looking for AND is it of type start elemenet (<example> but not </example>)

        ECHO '<hr>============= NODE FOUND ===================<br>';


        // Option 1
        //convert that into array so we can proceed with plain PHP
        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $temp = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($xml->expand(),true));
        $array = json_decode( json_encode($temp) , 1);


        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($array);
        echo "</pre>";


        // Option 2 Put current NODE contents into simpleXML object
        // $nodecontent = simplexml_load_string($xml->readOuterXML());
        // var_dump($nodecontent);

    }

}
```